# Double precision in C++ (or pow(2, 1000))

Tags: c++, precision, exponential

I'm working on Project Euler to brush up on my C++ coding skills in preparation for the programming challenge(s) we'll be having this next semester (since they don't let us use Python, boo!).

I'm on #16, and I'm trying to find a way to keep real precision for 2¹°°°

For instance:

```
int main(){
    double num = pow(2, 1000);
    printf("%.0f", num):
    return 0;
}
```

prints

> 10715086071862673209484250490600018105614050000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Which is missing most of the numbers (from python):

`>>> 2**1000`

> 10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376L

Granted, I can write the program with a Python 1 liner

```
sum(int(_) for _ in str(2**1000))
```

that gives me the result immediately, but I'm trying to find a way to do it in C++. Any pointers? (haha...)

Edit:

Something outside the standard libs is worthless to me - only dead-tree code is allowed in those contests, and I'm probably not going to print out 10,000 lines of external code...

Comment: Isn't the idea of those challenges that you should *not* be able to just write 2**1000? Wouldn't sound to challenging to me...

Comment: Project Euler, or the ACM style challenges?

Comment: @inf I've found that Python tends to let you cheat on a number of Project Euler questions

Comment: For ACM I know you are only allowed to use very few basic functions, with Project Euler I just assumed.

Comment: @Michael: That's what I suspected.

Comment: @inflagranti: Different languages which have different constructs built-in will be able to do different challenges easily. The primary part of the challenge is coping with the size of 2^1000. Python provides such functionality by default, making this a trivial Python challenge, but as the OP is experiencing, not necessarily in C++.

Also, if the OP wants to brush up his C++, it's definitely worth noting the printf vs cout.

Comment: PE doesn't have any standards. You can do it with pen and paper, python, c++, perl, or brainf*ck if you really want. You can't cheat if there aren't any rules.

Comment: The problems isn't to give all the digits but to give the sum of the digits, perhaps another approach is in order?

Comment: How can you say "You can't cheat if there aren't any rules." and then when someone suggests a library you say "but programming competitions tend to call 3rd party libraries cheating". Are there rules or not?

Comment: @Wayne You can't "cheat", but obviously the intent of the problem is to make you deal with a large number efficiently; doing `sum(map(int, str(2**1000)))` in Python doesn't really force you to do that

Comment: @GMan, Michael said that Python lets you "cheat" on PE, which is what I was referring to. The 3rd party libraries specifically ignored that I mentioned I was brushing up on my C++ coding skills for programming competitions, which is something completely different. Project Euler == no rules, ACM competition == rules. Using Python to get the answer in PE is not cheating, but using a 3rd party library at an ACM competition would be, unless I manually entered the dead-tree version. In this particular situation, it's useless to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just keep track of each digit in a char array, this is easy. Doubling a digit is trivial, and if the result is greater than 10 you just subtract 10 and add a carry to the next digit. Start with a value of 1, loop over the doubling function 1000 times, and you're done. You can predict the number of digits you'll need with `ceil(1000*log(2)/log(10))`, or just add them dynamically.

**Spoiler alert:** it appears I have to show the code before anyone will believe me. This is a simple implementation of a bignum with two functions, Double and Display. I didn't make it a class in the interest of simplicity. The digits are stored in a little-endian format, with the least significant digit first.

```
typedef std::vector<char> bignum;

void Double(bignum & num)
{
    int carry = 0;
    for (bignum::iterator p = num.begin();  p != num.end();  ++p)
    {
        *p *= 2;
        *p += carry;
        carry = (*p >= 10);
        *p -= carry * 10;
    }
    if (carry != 0)
        num.push_back(carry);
}

void Display(bignum & num)
{
    for (bignum::reverse_iterator p = num.rbegin();  p != num.rend();  ++p)
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(*p);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    bignum num;
    num.push_back(1);
    for (int i = 0;  i < 1000;  ++i)
        Double(num);
    Display(num);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a bignum library, such as [this one](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: Isn't the idea of those programming chalanges to come up with the corresponding algorithms onselves?

Comment: 3rd party stuff doesn't address my needs - I edited my question to make that clearer - but programming competitions tend to call 3rd party libraries cheating (unless I brought the dead-tree version and transcribed the code myself...)

Answer (score 3):

You probably need a pointer here (pun intended)

In C++ you would need to create your own bigint lib in order to do the same as in python.

Comment: You don't need a whole library, you just need a single function to do bigint addition or doubling and another to output the result. If you structure it as I describe in my own answer it becomes trivial.

Answer (score 2):

C/C++ operates on fundamental data types. You are using a `double` which has only 64 bits to store a 1000 bit number. `double` uses 51 bit for the significant digits and 11 bit for the magnitude.

The only solution for you is to either use a library like bignum mentioned elsewhere or to roll out your own.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** I just browsed to the Euler Problem site and found that Problem 13 is about summing large integers. The iterated method can become very tricky after a short while, so I'd suggest to use the code from Problem #13 you should have already to solve this, because `2**N => 2**(N-1) + 2**(N-1)`

<s>Using bignums is cheating and not a solution. Also, you don't need to compute 2**1000 or anything like that to get to the result. I'll give you a hint:</s>

Take the first few values of 2**N:

```
0 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 ...
```

Now write down for each number the sum of its digits:

```
1 2 4 8 7 5 10 11 13 ...
```

You should notice that (`x~=y` means x and y have the same sum of digits)

```
1+1=2, 1+(1+2)=4, 1+(1+2+4)=8, 1+(1+2+4+8)=16~=7 1+(1+2+4+8+7)=23~=5
```

Now write a loop.

Project Euler = Think before Compute!

Comment: Shouldn't the first value of 2**N be 1 as N**0 == 1?

Comment: for 13 I just used string stream to read a single number at a time and just summed it all up that way. The only problem on this one is they didn't give me the string representation of this number...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this sort of thing on a practical basis, you're looking for an arbitrary precision arithmetic package. There are a number around, including [NTL](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/), [lip](http://www.lehigh.edu/~bad0/snfs773/lip.html), [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), and [MIRACL](http://www.shamus.ie/).

If you're just after something for Project Euler, you can write your own code for raising to a power. The basic idea is to store your large number in quite a few small pieces, and implement your own carries, borrows, etc., between the pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `pow(2, 1000)` just 2 left-shifted 1000 times, essentially? It should have an exact binary representation in a double float. It shouldn't require a bignum library.

Comment: Yes, but power of 2 are usually exactly representable in floating point numbers.  The printed representation will depend on the implementation of the standard library.  As a matter of fact, on linux the OP program gives the same result as the Python one.