# Do data type sizes differ from computer to computer?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw

I am using Windows 7 with MinGW/GCC 4.7.1. I was trying to execute `double ans = pow(2,1000)` in C. I found that `ans` would not print correctly, no matter what I tried in terms of varying the data type.

However, I read (here, actually, at the very bottom of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389195/double-precision-in-c-or-pow2-1000) page) that if the same thing were run on a Linux computer, it would print correctly.

I am aware of the limits imposed on char, int, and long long that are in the limits.h file in my MinGW folder, but where are the restrictions of double and float? Do/could these vary from one OS or architecture to the next?

EDIT:

Here's the code, which prints out the truncated, zero-filled answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
   double ans = pow(2,1000);

   printf("%.0f", ans);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: your number is probably represented accurately in `double`, it's just the print routine that sucks.

Comment: This may merit another question, but perhaps it can be answered easily here: how would I get around the failing print routine? @tomasz

Comment: Please show some actual code. Your issue may or may not be related to type size. For example, if you use the wrong format specifier in a `printf()` call, then you will get wrong results.

Comment: Do you have `#include <math.h>` at the top of your source file? If not, the compiler is likely to assume that `pow` returns an `int` result and takes two `int` arguments (and you should also get a compiler warning).

Comment: @GregHewgill There's the code.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, I have included it, please see my code, it has been edited into the question.

Comment: and what was the output you got? (and what did you expect to see instead?)

Comment: I get the first 15-16 digits correctly displayed followed by the remainder of the number as '0's. I expected to see the 'zeroed' part of the number, as, well, non-zero (within reason, surely some of them are _really_ zero)

Comment: 15-16 correctly displayed digits is about all you can expect; that's typically how much precision type `double` gives you. You don't have a problem, you're just running into a minor variation in how different `printf` implementations treat *insignificant* digits. (And you could have saved all of us some time and effort if you'd told us that in the first place, by showing us the exact output your program was producing.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Interesting, thanks, although I'm not sure I completely grasp what you're saying - could you possibly recommend somewhere I could read about insignificant digits and how printf implementations treat them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Double precision in C++ (or pow(2, 1000))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389195/double-precision-in-c-or-pow2-1000)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question you're asking isn't related to the problem you're seeing.

It's very likely that all the systems you're using us the same representation for type `double`, namely 64-bit IEEE double-precision.

The value of `pow(2, 1000)` (or, more equivalently and more clearly, `pow(2.0, 1000.0)`, is 2.0<sup>1000</sup>. Since it's a power of two, it can be represented exactly -- but the relative precision of numbers that large is very coarse.

A `double` value is typically precise to only about 15 or so decimal digits.

Apparently the glibc implementation of `printf`, used on Linux systems, attempts to print the full decimal representation of the value, while other `printf` implementations replace some or all of the digits past the 15 or so *significant* digits with zeros. The latter is probably a bit easier to implement, but both approaches are valid.

Running your program on several different systems, I get the following results (with lines folded for readability):

```
10715086071862673000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

10715086071862673209484250490600018105614050000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361
22493198378815695858127594672917553146825187145285692314043598457757469857480393
45677748242309854210746050623711418779541821530464749835819412673987675591655439
46077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376
```

The last happens to be *exactly* equal to 2<sup>1000</sup>.

The number you're printing is unusual, in that it's very large *and* exactly representable -- and glibc goes to some extra effort to print it exactly. But more generally, floating-point values tend to be imprecise, and it's seldom worth worrying about any digits past the first few.

For example, `pow(2.0, 1000.0) + 1.0` *cannot* be represented exactly, and if you try to compute it, you'll probably get exactly the same result as `pow(2.0, 1000.0)`.

Comment: "you'll probably get exactly the same result" - I'd certainly hope so, since IEEE arithmetic requires that :-)

Comment: +1 this answer is a lot more informative than the accepted one.

Comment: And for what it's worth, I find `printf` (even the shell command) to be a great tool for computing exact values of huge powers of two, e.g. with `printf %f\\n 0x1p1000`.

Comment: @R..: Depends on the system. On Cygwin, which uses newlib rather than glibc, I get 259 trailing zeros before the decimal point.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. What I meant was to give a practical example of why it's nice to have an implementation that prints the correct exact value, not to say that I expect this to work on all implementations.

Answer (score 3):

The size of `float` and `double` **can** vary across implementations.

You are guaranteed that `double` is never smaller than `float`, and that `long double` is never smaller than `double` - similar to the guarantees for `long long`, `long`, `int`, `short`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the implementation of types like float and double *can* vary from platform to platform.

However, most common, modern platforms use IEEE 754, a standard for floating point types.  Thus it's unlikely that the binary representation for one of those types is going to be different unless you're on an unusual platform.

The other thread you mentioned seems to highlight potential differences in the accuracy of the printing routine.  That doesn't mean the representation is different (or of a different size).

Comment: So with that last line, are you saying that `ans` does contain the correct value for `2^1000` when I execute it? It just doesn't print correctly? As far as I can understand, `double` should be big enough to contain the number, but it just won't print out correctly.

Comment: Indeed, Microsoft's `printf` implementation is just notoriously bad. The C standard does not require printing more than `DECIMAL_DIG` significant digits even though there's an exact value to be printed, but a high-quality implementation will print the exact value anyway when possible because it's (potentially) more useful and just The Right Thing to do.